# Perl, using a linux command on users stored in a hash

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;


my @temparray;
my $count = 0;
my @lastarray;
my $lastbash;


#Opens the file /etc/shadow and puts the users with an uid over 1000 but less that 65000 into an array.
open( my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd") or die "/etc/passwd failed to open.\n";

    while (my $lines = <$passwd>) {
        my @splitarray = split(/\:/, $lines );
        if( $splitarray[2] >= 1000 && $splitarray[2] < 65000) {

            $temparray[$count] =$splitarray[0];
            print "$temparray[$count]\n";
            $count++;
        }
    }
close $passwd;

foreach (@temparray) {
    $lastbash = qx(last $temparray);
    print "$lastbash\n";
}
```

What I want to do is use the built in linux command "last" on all the users stored in the @temparray. And i want the output to be like this:

user1:10

user2:22

Where 22 and 10 being the number of times they logged in. How can I achieve this ?
I have tried several different ways but I always end up with errors.

Comment: Change `$temparray` with `$_` in `$lastbash`. Is your problem just to interpret the output from the `last` command?

Comment: @bolav Thanks very much! That worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should perform the task as requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;


my @temparray;
my $count = 0;
my @lastarray;
my $lastbash;


#Opens the file /etc/shadow and puts the users with an uid over 1000 but less that 65000 into an array.
open( my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd") or die "/etc/passwd failed to open.\n";

    while (my $lines = <$passwd>) {
        my @splitarray = split(/\:/, $lines );
        if( $splitarray[2] >= 1000 && $splitarray[2] < 65000) {

            $temparray[$count] =$splitarray[0];
            print "$temparray[$count]\n";
            $count++;
        }
    }
close $passwd;

foreach (@temparray) {
    my @lastbash = qx(last $_); #<----Note the lines read in go to the $_ variable. Note use of my. You also read the text into array.
    print $_.":".@lastbash."\n";  #<----Note the formatting. Reading @lastbash returns the number of elements.
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for keeping the seemingly unnecessary `utf8` pragma, the unused `@lastarray`, the poorly named variables, or the unconventional method of adding users to `@temparray`?

Comment: Often with such trivial scripts, bugs are few and optimizations unfortunately get neglected. As is always the case, many optimizations are possible. However that wasn't the focus of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `$count`, you could just do `push @temparray, $splitarray[0]`.

That said, I'm not sure why you need `@temparray` either... You can just run the command against the users as you find them.

```
my $passwd = '/etc/passwd';
open( my $fh, '<', $passwd )
  or die "Could not open file '$passwd' : $!";

my %counts;

# Get `last` counts and store them %counts
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    my ( $user, $uid ) = ( split( /:/, $line ) )[ 0, 2 ];
    if ( $uid >= 1000 && $uid < 65000 ) {
        my $last = () = qx{last $user};
        $counts{$user} = $last
    }
}
close $fh;

# Sort %counts keys by value (in descending order)
for my $user ( sort { $counts{$b} <=> $counts{$a} } keys %counts ) {
    printf "%s:\t %3d\n", $user, $counts{$user};
}
```